# iOS 8 UIApplicationMain crash since SDK 8 update

Tags: ios, crash, ios8, xcode6, callstack

Since I updated Xcode to 6.0.1 and iOS SDK to 8.0 my app no longer work on the device (running iOS 8 ofc).
But it works perfectly in the simulator.

The app crashes in UIApplicationMain before any call to the delegate has ever happened.
It seems either a value or key is null at CFTypeCollectionRetain.

I've tried

- Recreating certificates/provision profiles.
- Re-built with/without ARC.
- Tested both armv7 and arm64 builds.
- Xcode template (Game) application compiles and runs without probs.

Things to note

- Almost all code is C++, it's a game engine and are using bare minimum of OS services.
- Some global constructors (executed prior to main) are using pthreads primitives.
- No root view controller is created (legacy reasons), instead a custom view is created which uses CAEAGLLayer to "enable" GLES... but since the program doesn't reach the point where those are created I've ignored it for time being.
- Inside UIApplicationMain there is a call to [_UIFlippingView layerClass] which crashes; but cannot find any information about the UIFlippingView class whatsoever on Google...

I don't expect an answer but any good advise as to where look next would be very appreciated!

Callstack is as follows:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x185d9, 0x23f7646c CoreFoundation`__CFTypeCollectionRetain + 104, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
  * frame #0: 0x23f7646c CoreFoundation`__CFTypeCollectionRetain + 104
    frame #1: 0x23fd9168 CoreFoundation`__CFBasicHashAddValue + 564
    frame #2: 0x23ec06c0 CoreFoundation`CFBasicHashAddValue + 19048
    frame #3: 0x23ef745e CoreFoundation`CFDictionaryCreate + 178
    frame #4: 0x28a8d246 BackBoardServices`BKSHIDEventCreateClientAttributes + 186
    frame #5: 0x28a8d2ac BackBoardServices`___getHIDEventSystemClient_block_invoke + 36
    frame #6: 0x01fab740 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_once_f + 100
    frame #7: 0x28a8d318 BackBoardServices`BKSHIDEventRegisterEventCallback + 84
    frame #8: 0x274ab4a8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 576
    frame #9: 0x0008833c Traktor.Amalgam.App`main(argc=1, argv=0x01d3f9e8) + 196 at Main.mm:15
```

```
    CoreFoundation`__CFTypeCollectionRetain:
    0x23f76404:  push   {r4, r5, r7, lr}
    0x23f76406:  mov    r4, r1
    0x23f76408:  add    r7, sp, #0x8
    0x23f7640a:  cbz    r4, 0x23f7646c            ; __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 104
    0x23f7640c:  ldrd   r0, r1, [r4]
    0x23f76410:  cmp    r0, #0x0
    0x23f76412:  ubfx   r1, r1, #0x8, #0xa
    0x23f76416:  beq    0x23f7644a                ; __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 70
    0x23f76418:  movw   r2, #0xdf70
    0x23f7641c:  movt   r2, #0xe02
    0x23f76420:  add    r2, pc
    0x23f76422:  ldr    r2, [r2]
    0x23f76424:  cmp    r0, r2
    0x23f76426:  beq    0x23f7644a                ; __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 70
    0x23f76428:  movw   r2, #0x4aa4
    0x23f7642c:  movt   r2, #0xe03
    0x23f76430:  add    r2, pc
    0x23f76432:  ldr.w  r5, [r2, r1, lsl #2]
    0x23f76436:  cmp    r0, r5
    0x23f76438:  beq    0x23f7644a                ; __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 70
    0x23f7643a:  tst.w  r0, #0x1
    0x23f7643e:  beq    0x23f76456                ; __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 82
    0x23f76440:  mov    r0, r4
    0x23f76442:  blx    0x2400d1e0                ; symbol stub for: +[NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithCapacity:]
    0x23f76446:  cmp    r0, r5
    0x23f76448:  bne    0x23f76456                ; __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 82
    0x23f7644a:  mov    r0, r4
    0x23f7644c:  movs   r1, #0x0
    0x23f7644e:  pop.w  {r4, r5, r7, lr}
    0x23f76452:  b.w    0x23eafc38                ; _CFRetain
    0x23f76456:  movw   r0, #0xb93e
    0x23f7645a:  movt   r0, #0xe02
    0x23f7645e:  add    r0, pc
    0x23f76460:  ldr    r1, [r0]
    0x23f76462:  mov    r0, r4
    0x23f76464:  pop.w  {r4, r5, r7, lr}
    0x23f76468:  b.w    0x2400c0c8                ; objc_msgSend$shim
    0x23f7646c:  trap   -- TRAPPED HERE
    0x23f7646e:  nop
```

Inside UIApplicationMain code, interesting is the call to [_UIFlippingView layerClass] which crashes...

```
    0x274ab486:  blx    0x27b5b248                ; symbol stub for: roundf$shim
    0x274ab48a:  movs   r5, #0x0
    0x274ab48c:  movw   r0, #0x60f1
    0x274ab490:  movt   r0, #0x0
    0x274ab494:  add    r0, pc
    0x274ab496:  blx    0x27b595d8                ; symbol stub for: -[UIGravityBehavior _commonInit]
    0x274ab49a:  movw   r0, #0xfa8f
    0x274ab49e:  movt   r0, #0xfff9
    0x274ab4a2:  add    r0, pc
    0x274ab4a4:  blx    0x27b59068     -- THIS CALL           ; symbol stub for: +[_UIFlippingView layerClass]
    0x274ab4a8:  mov    r0, r5
    0x274ab4aa:  mov    r1, r11
    0x274ab4ac:  blx    0x27b5b248                ; symbol stub for: roundf$shim
    0x274ab4b0:  movw   r1, #0x23e4
    0x274ab4b4:  movt   r1, #0xb12
    0x274ab4b8:  add    r1, pc
    0x274ab4ba:  ldr    r1, [r1]
    0x274ab4bc:  blx    0x27b5b248                ; symbol stub for: roundf$shim
```

Answer (score 2):

Was able to fix the issue!!
Apparently Xcode had the bad idea of autogenerating a "Product Module Name" setting which didn't match "Product Name" and thus crashed the app when running on the device. This is mindbogglingly bad but imho what to expect of Xcode...

Comment: Could you explain more, I changed the same things, made both of them similar to $(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)
Still it did not solve the issue for me