# iOS9 keyboard crash on dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

I have this loginscreen that worked fine before iOS9. The keyboard has a Next button to go from the usernamefield to the passwordfield, and a Done button for dismissing the keyboard. However, on iOS 9 it crashes. I tested it on 8.4 and it worked. On iOS 9.0 and 9.1 it crashes.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == usernameField) {
        [passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == passwordField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I set the delegate properly.

So basically, when I press 'Next' or 'Done' 
crash:

```
CoreFoundation`__CFTypeCollectionRetain:
    0x2239dd5c <+0>:   push   {r4, r5, r7, lr}
    0x2239dd5e <+2>:   add    r7, sp, #0x8
    0x2239dd60 <+4>:   mov    r4, r1
    0x2239dd62 <+6>:   cbz    r4, 0x2239ddc4            ; <+104>
    0x2239dd64 <+8>:   ldrd   r0, r1, [r4]
    0x2239dd68 <+12>:  cmp    r0, #0x0
    0x2239dd6a <+14>:  ubfx   r1, r1, #0x8, #0xa
    0x2239dd6e <+18>:  beq    0x2239dda2                ; <+70>
    0x2239dd70 <+20>:  movw   r2, #0x7254
    0x2239dd74 <+24>:  movt   r2, #0x14d1
    0x2239dd78 <+28>:  add    r2, pc
    0x2239dd7a <+30>:  ldr    r2, [r2]
    0x2239dd7c <+32>:  cmp    r0, r2
    0x2239dd7e <+34>:  beq    0x2239dda2                ; <+70>
    0x2239dd80 <+36>:  movw   r2, #0x6240
    0x2239dd84 <+40>:  movt   r2, #0x14d1
    0x2239dd88 <+44>:  add    r2, pc
    0x2239dd8a <+46>:  ldr.w  r5, [r2, r1, lsl #2]
    0x2239dd8e <+50>:  cmp    r0, r5
    0x2239dd90 <+52>:  beq    0x2239dda2                ; <+70>
    0x2239dd92 <+54>:  tst.w  r0, #0x1
    0x2239dd96 <+58>:  beq    0x2239ddae                ; <+82>
    0x2239dd98 <+60>:  mov    r0, r4
    0x2239dd9a <+62>:  blx    0x2243208c                ; symbol stub for: -[__NSFileSecurity getGroup:]
    0x2239dd9e <+66>:  cmp    r0, r5
    0x2239dda0 <+68>:  bne    0x2239ddae                ; <+82>
    0x2239dda2 <+70>:  mov    r0, r4
    0x2239dda4 <+72>:  movs   r1, #0x0
    0x2239dda6 <+74>:  pop.w  {r4, r5, r7, lr}
    0x2239ddaa <+78>:  b.w    0x222e6ce8                ; _CFRetain
    0x2239ddae <+82>:  movw   r0, #0x3256
    0x2239ddb2 <+86>:  movt   r0, #0x13fb
    0x2239ddb6 <+90>:  add    r0, pc
    0x2239ddb8 <+92>:  ldr    r1, [r0]
    0x2239ddba <+94>:  mov    r0, r4
    0x2239ddbc <+96>:  pop.w  {r4, r5, r7, lr}
    0x2239ddc0 <+100>: b.w    0x22430e10                ; objc_msgSend$shim
    0x2239ddc4 <+104>: movw   r0, #0x332e
    0x2239ddc8 <+108>: movs   r3, #0x0
    0x2239ddca <+110>: movt   r0, #0x1223
    0x2239ddce <+114>: movw   r2, #0x116d
    0x2239ddd2 <+118>: add    r0, pc
    0x2239ddd4 <+120>: movt   r2, #0xc
    0x2239ddd8 <+124>: ldr    r0, [r0]
    0x2239ddda <+126>: add    r2, pc
    0x2239dddc <+128>: strd   r2, r3, [r0, #8]
->  0x2239dde0 <+132>: trap   
    0x2239dde2 <+134>: nop
```

The crash happens on the line with the '->'

I saw this post, but it didn't help:
[iOS9 dismissing keyboard causes crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552986/ios9-dismissing-keyboard-causes-crash)

I could really use some help figuring this out.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I found out, it has something to do with my UIFont category supplying all the views with my custom font.

Comment: Do you have the Exception breakpoint enabled?

Comment: Tried it, but same problem and same log

Comment: Are you doing something unusual with fonts?  Maybe even changing the font on any of the text fields?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960255/ios-8-uiapplicationmain-crash-since-sdk-8-update

Comment: @Avi I use a custom font yes

Comment: I'm at a loss. Sorry.

Comment: I commented out my category facilitating the font, and now it doesnt crash.  So it has something to do with the font!

Comment: can you send a pic of error message

Comment: The only error message I get is the above log

Comment: your logic seems a liitle confusing.clear me if you want this-> if textfield is username, then start typing. then you hit enter password becomes first responder, then when you return, it should resign. right?

Comment: first change your logic to:

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == usernameField) {
        [passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    } else if (textField == passwordField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo, the solution seems to have almost nothing to do with the keyboard. I had a CustomFont which I set by creating a UIFont category. In that category I swapped out some methods to provide the customFont to all UI Elements. Somehow the app ran fine until the textField was done editing, then I propably swapped out a method that didn't exist after the iOS 9 update. By commenting out that line  everything worked again. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I think ....

Issue was with UIViewController category

dealloc method was overridden to clean up notification callbacks.

And it caused a crash on iOS 9. Probably due to the fact [super dealloc] wasn't called (due to ARC restrictions)

Solution - remove dealloc method from category to the UIViewController subclasses.....

Comment: If you click the link in my question, that is exactly what it says there and like I mentioned it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

First set textfield tag then put this code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    // Try to find next responder
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
    if (nextResponder) {
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}
```